# Errors thrown when integrating Storybook with Webpack 5 React app

Tags: reactjs, storybook, webpack-5

I am trying to set up Storybook to my React application which is using Webpack 5. I am getting 2 errors and haven't been able to resolve them: 1) complaining that I am missing an appropriate loader to handle the file type; 2) it is unable to find stories in my storybook. I tried to follow examples I saw online and the documentation but still seem to be stuck. So my question is what am I missing/doing wrong in order to successfully set up storybook and actually see my stories?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I am missing anything code or information that you may need - I unfortunately cannot put a link to repo since it's private.

/.storybook/main.js

```
const path = require('path');
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      module: {
        ...config.module,
        rules: [ 
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [          
          {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  importLoaders: 1,
              },
              
          },
          {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                  sourceMap: true,
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: [postcssImport()],
              },
          },
          {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                  sassOptions: {
                      sourceMap: true,
                      includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
                  },
              },
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: { ...config.resolve },
};
},
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.js",
    "../src/**/**/*.stories.js",
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ],
}
```

component storybook file (/src/membership-status/index.stories.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { MembershipStatus } from './index';

export default {
  title: 'Components/MembershipStatus',
  component: MembershipStatus,
  args: {
   status: 'member',
  },
};

const Template = (args) => (
  <MembershipStatus { ...args } />
);

export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

This is my error:
[image]

Comment: You have `babel-loader` configured to run for `.scss` files which is wrong. Should be `.js` files.

Comment: Ah yes, wow total oversight. Thanks, it solved that specific error. I have a new error appearing but that's maybe for another post.